# PDO Suggest refine results different than wildcard symbol

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a PDO query to be searchable not only by the whole string but also by first letter or last letter anything like this. My question is what approach I have to take to achieve this goal.

My original idea was to use wildcard symbol and something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM idname WHERE field LIKE CONCAT('%', :field , '%')
```

but this option for me is not working since I am getting an error:

> Warning: Division by zero in**
>
> Warning: Division by zero in E:\xampp\htdocs\search-contact.php on line 111
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1' in E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php:451 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php(451): PDOStatement->execute() #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\search-contact.php(125): pagination->execute() #2 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\class\pagination.php on line 451

**My code ad the moment is the following:**

```
try
{

$paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM idname WHERE field LIKE :field', $options);
            

}
catch(paginationException $e)
{
    echo $e;
    exit();
}

$paginate->bindValue(':field', $_POST['field'] , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$paginate->execute();
```

Any suggestions are welcome ?

Comment: missing `'` on your query. typo here, or in your real code? plus... exactly where is this error coming from? there's no `/` for division anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using PDO you have to put the wildcards in the parameter, so it would look like:

```
$paginate->bindValue(':field', '%'.$_POST['field'].'%' , PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: If I put it like this with one parameter it works but If I have more binded values and I add it to them also, the query is showing everything like it is SLECT *

Comment: You didn't say anything about changing SELECT *, are you trying to change what is selected or what is in the WHERE clause?

Comment: I mean if I have something like this: SELECT * FROM idname WHERE field LIKE :field OR field2 LIKE :field2

Comment: Yes, that will still SELECT * , because `SELECT *` means all columns. When you use `WHERE` you are then limited the rows.

Comment: the actual question is answered, but I will have to keep investigating since the goal is to have various fields and no matter in which you will input something will display result. using the same wild card filtration.